# Capture output from console app started by daemon

Tags: c++, c++11

How is it possible to capture the output from a console app, if it's started by a daemon process in Ubuntu Server 18.04? For a non-daemon process I usually use this:

```
string myexec(const char* cmd) 
{
    array<char, 128> buffer;
    string result = "";
    unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
    if (!pipe) 
    {
        result = "FAIL";
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) 
    {
        result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Running this, as is, from the daemon doesn't fail, just returns empty.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't. A daemon runs detached. That's what makes it a daemon.

Usually a daemon will log somewhere (e.g. via `syslog` on Linux) and you can observe the log target for information.

Otherwise, don't run it as a daemon.

Comment: How detachment related to standard output of child console process?

Comment: @Slava https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)#Unix-like_systems

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit any workaround. I need the output from a console app, that I don't control, in my daemon. Any pointer in how to achieve that?

Comment: And? How is controlling terminal is related to standard output and why existance or non existance of one affects abuility to redirect output of child process? Do you want to say I cannot run a process from crontab and redirect its output to a file?

Comment: @MiguelE it depends what that app do and why it does not produce output. I believe this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Slava is it possible change the popen call to make the app write the output to a file?

Comment: @MiguelE it is possible not to use `popen()` but you need to find out first why there is no output. Run this console app from shell with redirected output. Does it produce  data?

Comment: @Slava works fine from terminal, or if I use the above procedure from another non-deamon app I compile.

Comment: It is funny how rep makes people +1 incorrect answer

Comment: @MiguelE it needs investigation, for example running it with `nohup`, unfortunately this is not format for SO.

Comment: @Slava Feel free to write a competing answer instead of complaining about people voting against you!